# Проблема с кодировкой autocomplete

Tags: java, ajax, autocomplete

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    $("#patientName").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "ajaxRequest",
                type : "GET",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1251",
                data : {
                    term : request.term
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});});
```

Причина в том что когда вытаскиваю с запроса строку (введеную в поле) вместо русских символов выводятся крякозябры.

Как исправить ?

```
package servlets;

import backend.MySQLQueries.MySQLPatient;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@WebServlet("/ajaxRequest")

public class AjaxRequest extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            resp.setContentType("application/json charset=windows-1251");
            String inputName = req.getParameter("term");
            System.out.println(inputName);
            List<String> patients = new MySQLPatient().searchPatients(inputName);
            String searchPatients = new Gson().toJson(patients);
            resp.getWriter().write(searchPatients);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте так - charset=utf-8

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. Может есть какой нибудь способ перевести их в кириллицу ?

Comment: проверьте ваши файлы как они записаны, должно быть utf-8 - ajaxRequest к примеру

Comment: Это java сервлет, по умолчанию там utf-8

Comment: @javax покажите код сервлета

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите, пожалуйста